# Usage of Range Based Loop for Vector of Pointer

Tags: c++11

**Hi, I am amateur. I'm stuck on range based loops.**

I know how to use this:

```
std::vector<ExampleClass> vec;
```

But I don't know this one:

```
std::vector<ExampleClass*> vec;
```

which one should I use?

## 1:

```
for (auto x : vec)
```

## 2

```
for (auto& x : vec)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not a c++ expert, however I know that vectors are always passed as reference, not as value... So I think the first should be more correct

Comment: It is often reasonable to pass vectors by reference, because it saves you the copying. But for both options neither is vector passed by value nor by reference! The **element** is passed by value or by reference into the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

The first gives you a **copy** of the actual pointer for each loop cycle.
It follows that:

- the pointer points to address in the memory where the object of ExampleClass resides
- you have access to the object by dereferencing with `*x`
- changing the pointing address of the pointer will **not** have any effect outside the scope of the for-loop

The second one gives you **reference** to the pointer stored in the actual element of the vector.
It follows that:

- you can do the same things as with the first option
- **and** you could let pointer point to a new address in memory and this is also going to take effect outside the scope of the for-loop

**Important**
If you use the last option you may end with a memory leak, if there is no pointer left pointing to the ExampleClass object **created with new**!

You have to **delete** every element of the vector created with **new**!

Therefore prefereable, is the usage of `unique_ptr` or `smart_ptr`! Using smart pointers leaves the ownership and destruction semantics up to them.

I would use the second one, because it saves you a copy, but the first one is saver and the copy of a pointer is inexpensive (see comment below by Olaf).

Or `for (auto const& x : vec)` ;-)

Comment: If there's no need to modify the pointer, the first one is preferred. When using the second form, you have an additional indirection, when accessing the `ExampleClass` object.